# No module named 'sink' after import tidylib

Tags: python

I have installed tidy by "conda install -c conda-forge tidy-html5" and then installed pytidylib
by "conda install -c hargup/label/pypi pytidylib".

The installation is fine. But when I do "import tidylib" I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a3a284945f3a> in <module>
----> 1 import tidylib

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tidylib\__init__.py in <module>
     23 import re
     24 import platform
---> 25 from sink import create_sink, destroy_sink
     26 
     27 __all__ = ['tidy_document', 'tidy_fragment', 'release_tidy_doc']

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sink'
```

I can't find any solution to the issue above. The internet is showing a lot on "
Error running kitchen_sink.py after installing kivyMD" which is not related. Has anyone managed to make tidylib work in window's environment? I'm running python on Juptyer.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command `conda install sink`.
If that does not work try creating a virtual environment using `conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda` then activate environment by `conda activate yourenvname` Install additional Python packages to a virtual environment by `conda install -n yourenvname [package]` to deactivate environment `conda deactivate`.
Else try using pip install to install the modules outside anaconda.

First try these outside Jupyter to check whether everything is fine then in Jupyter.